# How do I find details of this python package (__main__)?

Tags: python, program-entry-point, osmnx

I am looking at this script:

https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/master/osmnx/stats.py

On line 15, there is this:

`from .simplify import clean_intersections`

I tried to import it but got this message:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.simplify'; '__main__' is not a package`

I tried to search for the package on conda, I couldn't find anything.

How do I proceed?

I get a similar message for lines 16-20, eg:

`from .utils import log`

returns:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.utils'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: That is not a script. You are not supposed to run it like a script. You are having this problem because you're trying to run it like a script.

Comment: So what do I do then? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Install OSMnx, `import osmnx`, and do whatever task you wanted to use OSMnx to do.

Comment: There are instructions on the website.

Comment: I already have osmnx installed and imported. I have already defined the street network. I am trying to run this to calculate the stats.

Comment: So what does `__main__` refer to?

Comment: @SuperShoot I did look at that one, but I thought that my problem was different. But maybe it is because I don't know what `__main__` is referring to.

Comment: Here is python doc for `__main__` https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: Thanks. So do you know why it doesn't work in my instance? Do you know how I can fix it? Because I don't.

Comment: But basically, as far as python is concerned, the module that you are executing from the command line is called `__main__`, not the name of the module. Any module that you import into the module that you execute from within is called whatever it's filename is.

Comment: Yep, that is library code, not application code. It's not made to be executed from within the module that it is defined in. In another module do `from osmnx.stats import basic_stats` (for example, but import whatever function you want).

Comment: If you understand the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time you'll have it covered.

Comment: Thanks. Will read.

Comment: The comments here seem to answer this question pretty thoroughly. I want to add that if you're interested in working with OSMnx, you first might want to read through the installation instructions, documentation, and examples here: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/